# How to improve rails record update? (when many associated records exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I have rails records (items) where each is linked to 300-800 number of associated records (item_modifiers).

Most of the associated records (item_addons) are untouched every time I update the primary record (item) from my web form. This seems to be a big performance problem because I see every association record (item addon) being selected and saved.

What are some solutions to improve performance?

Web form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>  
    <%= f.input :name, label: "Name", required: true, placeholder: 'Buffalo Pizza' %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :addons, f.object.addons.order(priority: :desc) do |addon| %>
      <%= render 'shared/addon_fields', f: addon, cache: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Group', f, :addons, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  def update    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to "/sections/#{@item.section.to_param}", notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: I use the cocoon gem so I load all the associated records on the web form. And then I call item.update(parameters) in my controller

Comment: @jvillian added code